# Trying to use ifstream.read to get data into vector

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream, exif

Trying to read a part of a file into a vector structure.
Specifically trying to read exif data just using standard library.
This code compiles but the vector ("buffer") is empty.

Been working on this for a couple of days. Learning C++. More experienced with PHP. I know - I should probably be working on some basics rather than this but this is more fun. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void File_iterate ( const std::string* Filename  ) {

    std::ifstream infile ( *Filename, std::ios::binary );
    if ( !infile ) { std::cout << "Error: file unavailable\n"; exit(1); }

    infile.seekg( 0xE1, std::ios::beg ); // Seek to the position of the 0xE1 tag
    long CopyFrom = infile.tellg();
 
    unsigned short length;
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&length), sizeof(length) ); // Read the two bytes following the 0xE1 tag to obtain the length of the exifData

    infile.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
    std::cout << "Length of exifData:  " << length << " bytes.\n";
    std::cout << "Size of file:     " << infile.tellg() << " bytes\n";
    long CopyTo = CopyFrom + length;
    std::cout << "Exif Position: " << CopyFrom << " - " << CopyTo << "\n";
 
    std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(length);
 
    infile.seekg( 0xE1, std::ios::beg ); // Reset input stream
    infile.read( (char*)buffer.data() , length); // <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK :(
  
    std::cout << "Length of buffer: " << buffer.size() << " bytes\n" ;
 
    infile.close();
 
    for ( int i : buffer ) {
        if ( buffer[i] == 0xE1 ) { std::cout << buffer[i]; }
        if ( buffer[i] == 0x9003 ) { std::cout << buffer[i]; }
    }
```

Comment: `infile.seekg( 0xE1, std::ios::beg );` seeks to the position 225 in the file from the beginning of the file.

Comment: You never change the length of the `buffer`. It's size is 0. Reading into it is UB. You need to `resize` it to `length`, as opposed to `reserve`

Comment: Change `buffer.reserve(length);` to `buffer.resize(length);`

Comment: Neither `reserve` nor `read` will change the size of your vector, you want `resize` not `reserve`. Or you could just construct the vector at the correct size in the first place `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer(length);`

Comment: Changing to buffer.resize() did the trick. Now it reads just the bytes that I wanted. And yeah, I see it now that seekg() takes me to position 225, not the tag that I'm looking for. 

Atleast I'm getting a range :) Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.